# HTML table with conditional rows

Tags: html, html-table, handlebars.js

I'm using html templates to deliver email to my customers. The template holds a table, and I need this table to show or hide rows based on the data it's receiving. The data is injected to the HTML using `handlebars`.

I tried to add conditional `if` to the table, which works fine on the browser, but not when seeing the email:

```
<table class="tg">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="tg-0pky">Name</th>
         <th class="tg-0pky">{{ recipientName }}</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {{#if recipientId}}
      <tr>
         <td class="tg-0pky">ID</td>
         <td class="tg-0pky">{{ recipientId }}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/if}}
      {{#if recipientBank}}
      <tr>
         <td class="tg-0pky">Bank</td>
         <td class="tg-0pky">{{ recipientBank }}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/if}}
      {{#if recipientBranch}}
      <tr>
         <td class="tg-0pky">Branch</td>
         <td class="tg-0pky">{{ recipientBranch }}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/if}}
      {{#if recipientAccountNumber}}
      <tr>
         <td class="tg-0pky">Account number<br/></td>
         <td class="tg-0pky">{{ recipientAccountNumber }}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/if}}
      {{#if recipientAccountType}}
      <tr>
         <td class="tg-0pky">Account type</td>
         <td class="tg-0pky">{{ recipientAccountType }}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/if}}
      <tr>
         <td class="tg-0pky">Amount to receive</td>
         <td class="tg-0pky">{{ recipientReceive }}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

When receiving the email:
[image: email table]

When I receive the email, the rows are shown or not based on the data injected, but the table loses its formatting.

I've read that using a script is not the best way to handle this, because it's not a good practice to use scripts in email.

How can I dynamically show or hide the rows if the variable is present or not?

Comment: It sounds like your issue has to do with the styling of the table rather than with the rendered output.

Comment: But if I remove the conditional `if`, it renders just fine

Comment: Are you sending the uncompiled template in your email?! You want to compile your template and then execute the compiled function to produce the email body to be sent. This will require using Handlebars server-side (using Node), rather than in the client (browser).

Comment: No, the template already receives the variables. But I'm sending the HTML like in the post

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. I don't know if you mean that your email HTML contains the Handlebars template tags (`{{#if recipientId}}`, etc.) or not.